# 3D Array in Python with mutliple data types

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I need to create a 3D array in numpy which has multiple data types.

```
arr[int][str][int]
```

I have tried using `np.newaxis` combined with `rec.array`.

EDIT:
I intend to have the first column being text, or a string. 
Then the second column to hold integer values.

This then spans across multiple tables being a 3D array.

[image]

Like in this picture, with each table, holding just two columns. 
The first holds strings, the second holds integer values

Comment: Wait, how does this work? Do you index the arrays with an int, then a str, then an int? Why won't dictionaries work for you?

Comment: It may help others if you described what type of data you're trying to store, and what you intend to do with it.

Comment: Sorry no those are the data types which occur. So in the array the first column is a string, second is an int. And these span accross multiple "tables" being a 3D array.

Comment: You can use a record array, as answered, but I often find it more convenient to keep separate aligned arrays, i.e. one of strings, another of ints, both of same shape and with corresponding values stored in the same position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `np.recarray` like shown below:

```
a = np.recarray(4,dtype=[('col1',int),('col2','|S10'),('col3',int)])
a['col1'] = range(4)
a['col2'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
a['col3'] = range(11,15)

print a
# [(0, 'a', 11) (1, 'b', 12) (2, 'c', 13) (3, 'd', 14)]
```

if you want to go for a `2D` array, use `dtype=object`:

```
a = np.array([[0,1,2,3],['a','b','c','d'],[11,12,13,14]], dtype=object)

print a
#[[0 1 2 3]
# ['a' 'b' 'c' 'd']
# [11 12 13 14]]
```

Comment: Thanks, 
I add a = a[:,np.newaxis] to end line which solved it.